# Java, static and instance methods with same name

Tags: java

My code will start on of following Line445

I currently working on my college assignment and as part of requirement,

I must make some of static and instance methods with having same name.

Such as I require to make both instance/static methods named isPrime()

What should I do?

Edit/Add/Screenshot
It worked!
[image]

Edit/Add/Screenshot
[image]

```
 // class
    public class MyInteger {
        // Field
        private int num;

        public MyInteger(int someNum){
            num = someNum;
        }

        //Method

        private void setNum(int setNum){
            num = setNum;
        }

        public int getNum(int getNum){
            return getNum;
        }
        public int toInteger(){
            num = Integer.valueOf(num);
            return num;
        }

        public boolean isPrime(){

            if (num < 2){
                //prime number must be larger than 1
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                //if any number result 0 reminder until self, it is not prime
                if(num %  i == 0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: The parameter types must be different in that case.

Comment: Did you try it? What code did you use? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @khelwood Yes
My current code is here.
https://pastebin.com/AaiWqb1H

My code will start on line 445

I try with public boolean isEven(); and isEven(int x); but caused the following error.
Duplicate method isEven() in type Assignment05.MyIntegerJava(67109219)

I attempt with adding the class in class, I got following error
The member type isEven cannot be declared static; static types can only be declared in static or top level typesJava(16777527)

Comment: I suggest you include a [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two methods with the same name so long as their parameters (the input from the brackets) are different. So for example you could have

```
public boolean isPrime() { ... }
public static boolean isPrime(int num) { ... }
```

but not

```
public boolean isPrime() { ... }
public static boolean isPrime() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: Let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to accept the answer